I'm trying to make a dataframe, from json data in Python
I want to make dataframe with headers and data



Column A
Column B




Cell 1
Cell 2


Cell 3
Cell 4



When I run the code:
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json


response = requests.get('https://kp.gfz-potsdam.de/app/json/?start=2024-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&end=2024-04-21T23%3A59%3A59Z&index=Kp&status=def#kpdatadownload-143')
response_json = json.loads(response.text)
df = pd.read_json(response_json)
print(df)

Receive:
C:\Python310\python.exe C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\solar\solar2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\solar\solar2.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = pd.read_json(response_json)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 791, in read_json
    json_reader = JsonReader(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 904, in __init__
    data = self._get_data_from_filepath(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_json.py", line 944, in _get_data_from_filepath
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 728, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 472, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>

Process finished with exit code 1

How to solve this problem? Please help.

I think you need to remove the metadata element from the JSON before turning it into a dataframe.

Did you read the docs? read_json's path_or_buf parameter needs to be "a valid JSON str, path object or file-like object", which does not include dict.

What output are you expecting exactly? Please make a [mre] and include a snippet of response_json so that all the details are here in the question. I checked it for myself and it looks like the actual column labels should be datetime, Kp, and status.

Thanks a lot for yours answers! You are right the output should be: column labels shoud be datetime/Kp/status. The rows should be dates.

This is because json.loads returns a dict, and pd.read_json requires path_or_buf.
You can use the following code:
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

response = requests.get(
    "https://kp.gfz-potsdam.de/app/json/?start=2024-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&end=2024-04-21T23%3A59%3A59Z&index=Kp&status=def#kpdatadownload-143"
)
response_json: dict = json.loads(response.text)

df = pd.DataFrame([response_json])
print(df)


json.loads(response.text) can be simplified to response.json

response_json doesn't need to be put in a list.

Without the list, there will be a ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.

That's because there's an extra metadata: object in the JSON that needs to be removed. Everything else is lists that should turn into a proper dataframe.

Thank you very much for your advice! I'll try to implement them.
